# JavaFX UI elements hover style not rendering correctly after resizing application window

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, resize

At times, certain UI elements that have a hover style will not render at all and a white box is left in it's place.  This only happens after I resize the application window and when the UI element is completely outside of the original bounds of the application window.  The button shown in the images below also does not immediately render correctly after removing the mouse pointer from the hover position, so the issue likely would occur whenever the button needs to be repainted.

["Device Logging" button is being hovered by the mouse, before resizing the window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd6H1.png)

[After resizing the window. Both the "Device Logging" and "Misc Tests" buttons are 100% outside of the original bounds of the window. The "Cloud Server Migration" button however is still rendering correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpYk7.png)

I have set styles, but removing them has no effect.  The issue only seems to appear when there is other processing taking place, such as running the firmware update function.  That tells me that there may be something taking up UI time, but I would have expected that to affect every UI element, not just certain ones.

One other note, the UI was converted from Swing to JavaFX, so all of the threading did not include the use of Task or Platform.runlater().  I have since made sure all UI updates are using Platform.runlater(), but I have not yet converted all of the original threads that don't update the UI to Tasks.  Below I am including the framework of running a firmware update.

Edit: Was able to reproduce the issue without starting a firmware update, so I don't think it has anything to do with processing blocking UI rendering.  The issue occurred only after using some of the UI.  As such I removed the code that was posted above.  This leads me to believe it has more to do with the actual layout of the UI.

Comment: Nothing obvious jumps to mind, and I suspect without a minimal example, that reproduces the issue, you won't get this resolved here...

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have figured out the issue. I use a ListView to hold an Object and a cellfactory to render each of the cells with a custom UI. When populating the list with items, additional threads are spawned to retrieve information for each Object within the cell. The variables associated with the Object are bound to a view property within the custom UI. I was not using Platform.runlater() to update these properties with the new information. After updating the sets to runlater, the issue appears to have been fixed.