# JavaFX WebView scrolled issue

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I've developed an application using JavaFX that, in part, uses a WebView. However, I've noticed that when either by the user or programmatically via JS, the WebView is scrolled to the bottom or just near the bottom, strange things seem to happen. I am specifically hoping for some way to stop this behavior, and still need to allow scrolling in both senses. It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308591/) question but they are not the same. The rest of my post explains what is happening.

If you scroll to the bottom and resize the window to be larger than previously and hover over other JavaFX controls in the window, they become white boxes.

To illustrate, suppose you have the following window:

[image]

Scroll to the bottom and resize the window to be larger than previously and then hover over the JavaFX button and TextBox, who both disappear when you do so:

[image]

This happens on at least Windows 10 with Java8u111 and Java8u51. I've made an example to demonstrate this:

example.Main.java

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Example.fxml"));
        BorderPane rootWindow = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootWindow);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

example.ExampleController.java

```
package example;

import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class ExampleController {
    @FXML private WebView webView;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load("https://stackoverflow.com");
        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener( (o, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (newVal == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                engine.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

example.Example.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="example.ExampleController">
   <center>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </WebView>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextField HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Button alignment="TOP_LEFT" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Is there a way I can stop this from happening or at least mitigate it?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, and I found a solution：
Add a parameter to jvm：**-Dprism.order=sw**

see:https://news.kynosarges.org/2016/04/09/javafx-and-java_tool_options/?tdsourcetag=s_pctim_aiomsg